# Spring Integration FTP connection with FtpOutboundGateway command 'get' without 'ls'

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I'm new to Spring Integration and I need to setup a FTP connection to a server which only accepts `GET` and `PUT` command.

I configured a `FtpOutboundGateway` and `@MessagingGateway` which is actually working.

However the `FtpOutboundGateway` with the setup

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpFetchFile")
    public MessageHandler getFile() {
    FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(this.ftpSessionFactory(), "get", "payload");
        gateway.setLocalDirectoryExpression(EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("#remoteDirectory")); 
        gateway.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
        return gateway;
    }
```

also does an `LS` command before the `GET`. Which is actually a nice way, to prove the file is there, but as the server is creating the file on the fly, the `LS` never will return any existing files and thus is running in the MessagingException from `org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.get(Message<?>, Session<F>, String, String, String, boolean)`:

```
failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: someFile.txt is not a file
```

Is there a way to retrieve a file with only Ftp `GET`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have such a restrictions and can perform only `GET`, consider the variant to use the `FtpOutboundGateway` with the `MessageSessionCallback`:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpFetchFile")
public MessageHandler getFile() {
    return new FtpOutboundGateway(this.ftpSessionFactory(), 
                     (session, requestMessage) -> {

            // Call Session.read() or Session.readRaw() and return the result of reading

                                  });
}
```

Comment: Or use an `FtpRemoteFileTemplate` in a service activator.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will have a look into this